# API Token into SOAP header for Professional Edition support

Tags: soap, http-headers, salesforce, token

Our app has successfully passed security review and on app exchange. The app uses meta data APIs to created remote site setting, but meta data APIs are not supported in professional edition. We have obtained a API token from Salesforce which we have inserted in the soap header as below. Though it functions as expected in the developer/enterprise edition, in professional edition we get 500(server error).
Anyone please suggest if there is something wrong with the below implementation and the way forward.

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + 
            '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+
                
                '<env:Header>' + 

                    '<urn:SessionHeader xmlns:urn="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' + 
                        '<urn:sessionId>sessionhere</urn:sessionId>' + 
                    '</urn:SessionHeader>' + 
                     '<CallOptions>' +
                    '<client>blah/blahtoken/</client>' + 
                    '</CallOptions>' +
                '</env:Header>' + 
                '<env:Body>' +
                     '<createMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' + 

                        '<metadata xsi:type="RemoteSiteSetting">' + 
                            '<fullName>Metadata</fullName>' +
                            '<description>Metadata API Remote Site Setting for Declarative Rollup Tool (DLRS)</description>' + 
                            '<disableProtocolSecurity>false</disableProtocolSecurity>' + 
                            '<isActive>true</isActive>' + 
                            '<url>https://some.ap4.visual.force.com</url>' +
                        '</metadata>' +
                    '</createMetadata>' +
                '</env:Body>' + 
            '</env:Envelope>';
```

Answer (score 0):

the 500 server error will be a SOAP response, look at the body for more details of the error.

The problem is likely that you CallOptions header is not in the correct XML namespace, it should be

```
<CallOptions xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <client>blah/blahtoken/</client>
</CallOptions>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I found this on the ISVforce document, and this is why the behaviour is not as expected as we are calling the API from JS with VF. Please suggest if any alternative . We need to add a remote site automatically. https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf

The Client ID has these properties. • You can't use the Client ID with the AJAX Toolkit in custom JavaScript, S-controls, or anywhere in your app where its value would be exposed to the end customer.